# Is there an example of a one to one and onto mapping between these two spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a convex open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with a smooth boundary. Is there an example of a one to one and onto mapping of the form $$L^{d+1}(\Omega) \to W^{1,d+1}(\Omega)$$

Comment: Should your map be a linear isomorphism? Or anything else apart of bijection? Else the question is bit strange: of course, these spaces both have cardinality continuum.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : bijection. I am seeking examples. not existence.

Answer (score 3):

The map $(-\Delta + 1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}: L^p (\Omega) \to W^{1, p}_0 (\Omega)$ is a linear bijection when $\Omega$ is smooth and $1 < p < +\infty$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary conditions.

When $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d$, this operator correspond to the convolution with the Bessel kernel of order $1$.

Comment: Is there a name for this function? It looks like a square root of sum of Laplacian and itself.

Comment: $\Delta$ on $\Omega$ needs a boundary condition.

Comment: I have added the boundary condition.